# Can I use "-" in django project name

Tags: django

While I am trying to create a new project in Django I got this error

```
command used : django-admin startproject test-service

'test-service' is not a valid project name. Please make sure the name is a valid identifier.
```

Then I tried with django-admin startproject test_service and it is working. Can you please confirm whether i can use dash in project name.
I am planning to do a uniq naming convention for upcoming projects also.

Comment: this will give you better idea https://groups.google.com/g/django-users/c/U-CfORZcfPg?pli=1

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot use a hyphen in the project or app name passed to `startproject` or `startapp`.

The name must be a valid identifier, this is verified by calling the function [`str.isidentifier`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isidentifier). The Python docs contain the definition of a valid identifier [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)